# How to get row count in sqlite using Android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, onitemclicklistener

I am creating task manager. I have tasklist and I want when I click on particular tasklist name if it empty then it goes on Add Task activity but if it has 2 or 3 tasks then it shows me those tasks into it in list form.

I am trying to get count in list. my database query is like:

```
public Cursor getTaskCount(long tasklist_Id) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM " + TABLE_TODOTASK + " WHERE " + KEY_TASK_TASKLISTID + "=?",
             new String[] { String.valueOf(tasklist_Id) });
    if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()!=0)
          cursor.moveToNext();
    return cursor;
}
```

In My activity:

```
list_tasklistname.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
            android.view.View v, int position, long id) {
                db = new TodoTask_Database(getApplicationContext());
                Cursor c = db.getTaskCount(id);
                System.out.println(c.getCount());
                if(c.getCount()>0) {    
                System.out.println(c);
                Intent taskListID = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddTask_List.class);
                task = adapter.getItem(position);
                int taskList_id = task.getTaskListId();
                taskListID.putExtra("TaskList_ID", taskList_id);
                startActivity(taskListID);
            }
            else {
                Intent addTask = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Add_Task.class);
                startActivity(addTask);
            }
        }
    });
    db.close();
}
```

but when I am clicking on tasklist name it is returning 1, bot number of tasks into it.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Using `DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries()`:

```
public long getProfilesCount() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    long count = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, TABLE_NAME);
    db.close();
    return count;
}
```

or (**more inefficiently**)

```
public int getProfilesCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    return count;
}
```

In Activity:

```
int profile_counts = db.getProfilesCount();
    db.close();
```

Comment: It is inefficient to load all rows; better use [queryNumEntries()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: If you are wanting to count rows with a certain condition, the `queryNumEntries()` method can also take `selection` and `selectionArgs` parameters. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])

Comment: @CL. queryNumEntries() is very useful, thanks for pointing out, saved many lines of code :)

Comment: To get a count you should never do getCount on a cursor. This will bring in all the results from the database into memory thus use a lot more memory. Instead you could use "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + TABLE_NAME. Then the result will be stored in column 0 of the cursor.

Answer (score 50):

Use [android.database.DatabaseUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils#queryNumEntries(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to get number of count.

```
public long getTaskCount(long tasklist_Id) {
        return DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(readableDatabase, TABLE_NAME);
}
```

It is easy utility that has multiple wrapper methods to achieve database operations.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer to OP's question. No need to write any SQL queries or load all the entries from the table. +1.

Comment: Best answer !!! This is the most simple answer and utilize the existing feature. Up to the 2nd top.

Answer (score 40):

`c.getCount()` returns `1` because the cursor contains a single row (the one with the real `COUNT(*)`). The count you need is the `int` value of first row in cursor.

```
public int getTaskCount(long tasklist_Id) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery(
        "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM " + TABLE_TODOTASK + " WHERE " + KEY_TASK_TASKLISTID + "=?",
         new String[] { String.valueOf(tasklist_Id) }
    );
    int count = 0;
    if(null != cursor)
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
          cursor.moveToFirst();    
          count = cursor.getInt(0);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }

    db.close();
    return count;
}
```

Comment: It means my database method is fine?

Comment: I just edited my answer: now the method should return directly the rows count.

Comment: there is one typo.. it should be cursor.getInt(0); and not c.getInt(0);

Answer (score 7):

I know it is been answered long time ago, but i would like to share this also:

This code works very well:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
long taskCount = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, TABLE_TODOTASK);
```

BUT what if i dont want to count all rows and i have a condition to apply?

DatabaseUtils have another function for this: `DatabaseUtils.longForQuery`

```
long taskCount = DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM " + TABLE_TODOTASK + " WHERE " + KEY_TASK_TASKLISTID + "=?",
         new String[] { String.valueOf(tasklist_Id) });
```

The `longForQuery` documentation says:

> Utility method to run the query on the db and  return the value in the first column of the first row.

```
public static long longForQuery(SQLiteDatabase db, String query, String[] selectionArgs)
```

It is performance friendly and save you some **time** and boilerplate code

Hope this will help somebody someday :)

Answer (score 5):

Change your getTaskCount Method to this:

```
public int getTaskCount(long tasklist_id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM " + TABLE_TODOTASK + " WHERE " + KEY_TASK_TASKLISTID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(tasklist_id) });
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int count= cursor.getInt(0);
    cursor.close();
    return count;
}
```

Then, update the click handler accordingly:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, android.view.View v, int position, long id) {
    db = new TodoTask_Database(getApplicationContext());

    // Get task list id
    int tasklistid = adapter.getItem(position).getTaskListId();

    if(db.getTaskCount(tasklistid) > 0) {    
        System.out.println(c);
        Intent taskListID = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddTask_List.class);
        taskListID.putExtra("TaskList_ID", tasklistid);
        startActivity(taskListID);
    } else {
        Intent addTask = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Add_Task.class);
        startActivity(addTask);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is not working? try logging the tasklist_id to logcat to make sure that you are using the expected id.

Comment: Your method is fine but I think I am getting wrong id from OnItemClick();

Comment: Instead of passing "id" to getTaskCount pass taskList_id from task.getTaskListId() - as you already do later in the if statement.

Comment: I can not do this because task is Task class object but addtask is ADDTask class object, addtask can't use adapter, how can i get position or id?

Comment: i have updated my answer with the code for the listener, does this work?

Comment: I have used cursor.getCount(); it is returning value

Answer (score 4):

In order to query a table for the number of rows in that table, you want your query to be as efficient as possible. [Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String)).

Use something like this:

```
/**
 * Query the Number of Entries in a Sqlite Table
 * */
public long QueryNumEntries()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    return DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, "table_name");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sooo simple to get row count:

```
cursor = dbObj.rawQuery("select count(*) from TABLE where COLUMN_NAME = '1' ", null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
String count = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(0)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you see what the **DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries()** does? It's awful!
I use this.

```
public int getRowNumberByArgs(Object... args) {
    String where = compileWhere(args);
    String raw = String.format("SELECT count(*) FROM %s WHERE %s;", TABLE_NAME, where);
    Cursor c = getWriteableDatabase().rawQuery(raw, null);
    try {
        return (c.moveToFirst()) ? c.getInt(0) : 0;
    } finally {
        c.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide more information on what queryNumEntries does exactly and why it is aweful? Thank you!

Comment: It goes 4 levels deep and executes lots of collateral code to do the same thing as I wrote in my answer. The code-size economy with using this helper library is doubtful

Comment: I agree, it's awful. Using count(*) is a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

looking at the sources of `DatabaseUtils` we can see that `queryNumEntries` uses a `select count(*)...` query.

```
public static long queryNumEntries(SQLiteDatabase db, String table, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs) {
    String s = (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) ? " where " + selection : "";
    return longForQuery(db, "select count(*) from " + table + s,
                selectionArgs);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Once you get the cursor you can do

```
Cursor.getCount()
```