# Cannot get the correct count of records after I deleting ListView item with ArrayAdapter in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite, android-arrayadapter

I have a ListView with some items and in each item there is a ImageButton for deleting this item.

The method for deleting the item is inside an ArrayAdapter which uses a view holder.

```
            //ALERT DIALOG FOR DELETE
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
            builder.setTitle("Delete All?");
            builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which)
                        {
                            dialog.dismiss();

                        }
                    });
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                        {
                            mHelper.deleteAll(gmid,true);                   //DELETE ITEM
                            remove(getItem(position));                          //REMOVE ITEM FROM LIST
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                            TextView txtGameCount = (TextView) ((Activity)getContext()).findViewById(R.id.txtGamesCount);
                            int GamesCount = mHelper.getGamesCount(tmid);       //GET COUNT OF ITEMS
                            txtGameCount.setText(String.valueOf(GamesCount));   //SET TEXT WITH NEW NUMBER OF ITEMS
                            dialog.dismiss();                                   //CLOSE DIALOG

                        }
                    });
            builder.show();
```

**My problem is that the TextView for displaying the number of items is displaying "0" and not the actual count of items.**

The count method is working while I am adding an item and it is the following:

```
public int getGamesCount(int id)
{
    String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLEG +" WHERE t_id="+ id +"";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    return cursor.getCount();
}
```

What I am doing wrong here?

thank you

Comment: mHelper.deleteAll(gmid,true);         you are removing all  item of adapter..

Comment: no Only the game with Id gmid

Comment: I used the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097748/how-to-get-row-count-in-sqlite-using-android and it worked but I dont understand why?

Comment: deleteAll() it makes to remove all data from adapter then how list will display here  ..?

Answer (score 0):

You are using deleteAll() which will delete all records. 
To delete a particular record use this function.

```
 public void deleteRecords(String table, String whereClause,
                              String[] whereArgs) {
        db.delete(table, whereClause, whereArgs);

    }
```

Then there is no need to call

> remove(getItem(position))

because

> notifydatasetchange()

will reset the list again. 
You have called deleteAll() and the n you are finding count so that will return 0 only because all records are deleted.