# SQLiteDatabase method to call to use the SELECT statement in an "if" statement?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to check if there are already 5 rows in my database, but I can't use the execSQL method to call SELECT because it returns void and nothing else seems to fit in an if statement. So is there a simple fix or do I have to go about this another way?

```
//add a new row to the database
public void addProduct(Products product){

    SQLiteDatabase db =  this.getWritableDatabase();
    if(db.execSQL("SELECT Count * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS) == 5){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME, product.get_productname());
        db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097748/how-to-get-row-count-in-sqlite-using-android refer this.

Comment: For **queries**, use `rawQuery()`. For **commands**, use `execSQL()`. If you know the difference between a SQL query and a SQL command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();   
if(DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, TABLE_PRODUCTS) == 5){ 
   ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
   values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME, product.get_productname()); 
   db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values); db.close(); 
 }
```