# set an int to value of rows in sql lite column

Tags: sql, sqlite

Simply trying to set an integer to be the size of the rows in one of my columns in my sql database.

```
int x = db.execSQL("SELECT COUNT"+ COL_2);
```

Not sure what the easiest way to do this would be. Thanks

```
public class DatabaseSQL extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "simpleNotes.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "titles_notes";
    private static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    private static final String COL_2 = "TITLES";
    private static final String COL_3 = "NOTES";

    public DatabaseSQL(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //creates table...
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, TITLES TEXT, NOTES TEXT )");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    public boolean insertData(int key, String title, String notes){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_1,key);
        contentValues.put(COL_2,title);
        contentValues.put(COL_3,notes);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
        if(result == -1){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Cursor getAllData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+ TABLE_NAME,null);
        return res;
    }

    public Integer deleteData (String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "ID = ?",new String[] {id});
    }
}
```

My plan is to get the size of the row of COL_2 then ->set the ID to be that size. My problem is that when I delete my data I need to have the number of rows so that I can set the ID in proportion to the size or rows.

Perhaps I can create a simple getter method to return this when called from another class?

Comment: Can you please add the Code of Col_2?

Comment: see my update to the question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097748/how-to-get-row-count-in-sqlite-using-android

Comment: This means you found your answer?

Comment: It works, but there are still some bugs. But I think I just fixed it....