# Xamarin Android SQLite data reading gives me the "SQLite.SQLiteException: no such table: tblLidhja" exception

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android, sqlite-net-pcl

I am trying to build an Android Xamarin Application. I have created an SQLite database named **regjistri.sqlite** . The database it's not corrupted, I can open it via SQLite browser on my PC. This database I have save it to my android Documents folder.
I am trying to access it like below via **sqlite-net-pcl** library.

```
string dbPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "regjistri.sqlite");
var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
var data = db.Query<object>("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblLidhja ");
```

Also I have gice the application the reading and writing permissions. When I debug it via USB cable, it give me the **"SQLite.SQLiteException: no such table: tblLidhja"** exception. Can someone help me whats may be wrong, or what should I change to read some data?

Comment: You mean instead of **var data = db.Query<object>("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblLidhja ");**  it should be **var data = db.Query<tblLidhja>("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblLidhja ");** ?

Comment: What is your actual `tblLidhja` class code and where is the `TableCreate` call in your code?

Comment: if the path does not exist SQLite will create an empty db for you - this is what I suspect is happening - your path is not correct.  Use File.Exists to verify

Comment: You have to call `db.CreateTable<tblLidhja>()` after the connection to DB is opened and before querying any data from it (that's what the exception is telling you - there is no such table in your DB). You can find an example at sqlite-net repo page: https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net

Answer (score 0):

Before getting data , first need to check whether this table is exist in data base .You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/data-access/using-sqlite-orm) to check .

By the way ,having a try with this way to get count from database:

```
var db = new SQLiteConnection("DbPath");
var stocksStartingWithA = db.Query<TableName>("SELECT * FROM DbNmae ");
int count = stocksStartingWithA.Count; //get count from table
```

Here is [similar discussion with java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097748/how-to-get-row-count-in-sqlite-using-android), but it also can be refer in xamrin project.